# Parsing FFMpeg AVPackets into h264 nal units

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

I am using **FFMpeg** To decode live video and stream it using **Live555**.i am able to decode video and getting the output AVPackets.
1. Convert the BGR Image to YUV422P format using FFMpeg's SWScale

```
// initilize a BGR To RGB converter using FFMpeg
ctx = sws_getContext(codecContext->width, codecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
tempFrame = av_frame_alloc();
int num_bytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_BGR24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);
uint8_t* frame2_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(num_bytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)tempFrame, frame2_buffer, PIX_FMT_BGR24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);

// inside the loop of where frames are being encoded where rawFrame is a BGR image
tempFrame->data[0] = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(rawFrame->_data);
sws_scale(ctx, tempFrame->data, tempFrame->linesize, 0, frame->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
```

For decoding each Frame

```
ret = avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &packet, frame, &got_output);
if(ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in encoding frame\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(got_output)
{
    //printf("Received frame! pushing to queue\n");
    OutputFrame *outFrame = new OutputFrame();
    outFrame->_data = packet.buf->data;
    outFrame->_bufferSize = packet.buf->size;
    outputQueue.push_back(outFrame);
}
```

Till here it works fine. i am able to write these frames to file and play it using VLC. after this i have to pass the output frame to Live555.i think AVPackets i am getting here doesn't need to be a single H264 Nal unit which is required by Live555.

How to break a AVPacket into Nal units which can be passed to Live555?

Answer (score 1):

H264VideoStreamDiscreateFramer expect data without the start code '\x00\x00\x00\x01'. 
It is needed to remove the 4 first bytes either in your LiveDeviceSource or inserting a FramedFilter to do this job.

Perhaps you can tried to use an H264VideoStreamFramer, like the testH264VideoStreamer test program.

If it could help, you can find one of my tries with live555 implementing an RTSP server feed from V4L2 capture https://github.com/mpromonet/h264_v4l2_rtspserver

Comment: unfortunately my V4L2 Capture doesn't give h264 data but raw YUV Data so i have to use encoder. i think my Live555 setup is fine but the problem is in ffmpeg encoded data which is giving bitstream in AVPacket not h264 Nal Units. if i pass h264 nal units to Live555, i think it will work. Can i configure ffmpeg (AVCodecContext) to give me H264 Nal units? if u have done something like this please let me know ..

Comment: Considering testH264VideoStreamer stream an H264 elementary stream (that contain the start code), I think the H264VideoStreamFramer  could work in your case. Otherwise with H264VideoStreamDiscreateFramer you need to remove the startcode in LiveDeviceSource<br/>Reading ffmpeg libavcodec/libx264.c and X264 encoder/encoder.c and common/bitstream.c show that encoding frame start with the startcode or with 4-byte size depending of b_annexb flag.